# the right regex expression in python

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I have a small problem to extract the words which are in bold:

**Médoc**, Rouge
2ème Vin, **Margaux**, Rosé
2ème vin, **Pessac-Léognan**, Blanc

I have to clarify more my question :
I'm trying to extract some information from web pages, so each time i found a kind of sentence but me i'm interesting in which is in bold. I give you the adress of the tree wab pages :

- (http://www.nicolas.com/page.php/fr/18_409_9829_tourprignacgrandereserve.htm)
- (http://www.nicolas.com/page.php/fr/18_409_8236_relaisdedurfortvivens.htm)

  re(r'\s*\w+-\w+-\w+|\w+-\w+|\w+[^Rouge,Blanc,Rosé]')

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the criteria here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use positive look ahead to see if `Rouge` or `Blanc` or `Rosé` is after the word we are looking for:

```
>>> import re
>>> l = [u"Médoc, Rouge", u"2ème Vin, Margaux, Rosé", u"2ème vin, Pessac-Léognan, Blanc"]
>>> for s in l:
...     print re.search(ur'([\w-]+)(?=\W+(Rouge|Blanc|Rosé))', s, re.UNICODE).group(0)
... 
Médoc
Margaux
Pessac-Léognan
```

Comment: Last output should be `Pessac-Léognan` not `Léognan`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, I think you caught him.

Comment: @alecxe -1 on your answer was from me(my connection got yanked so was not able to comment). +1 now ;)

Comment: @alecxe: You mean the serial downvote I just received? *shrug*, that'll be reverted tonight anyway. I am pretty sure who did that in any case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, he was very upset because of `eval()`.

Comment: @alecxe: if it is him, it's a pity he took it personally. I'll just avoid giving feedback next time, he'll just have to figure out on his own why a post got downvoted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters exactly, being explicit just don't work for some people. Actually cannot think of a valid reason to downvote your answers.

Comment: thank you for answer but I have to clarify more my question :
I'm trying to extract some information from web pages, so each time i found a kind of sentence but me i'm interesting in which is in bold. I give you the adress of the tree wab pages : 

- [link](http://www.nicolas.com/page.php/fr/18_409_9829_tourprignacgrandereserve.htm)

- [link](http://www.nicolas.com/page.php/fr/18_409_8236_relaisdedurfortvivens.htm)

- [link] (http://www.nicolas.com/page.php/fr/18_409_9068_leshautsdesmith.htm)

Comment: @xeroxSO well, that's actually completely changes the question. If the data is inside the web page - you need an HTML parser like `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml`, doing it with regex is not a best practice:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags.

Comment: thanks I think it's  fixed with expression [\w-]+)(?=\W+(Rouge|Blanc|Rosé)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's always the second to last term in the comma separated list? You can split and select the second to last, example:

```
>>> myStr = '2ème vin, Pessac-Léognan, Blanc'
>>> res = myStr.split(', ')[-2]
```

Otherwise, if you want regex alone... I'll suggest this:

```
>>> res = re.search(r'([^,]+),[^,]+$', myStr).group(1)
```

And trim if necessary for spaces.

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Okay, are there perhaps functions having names containing `str`?

Comment: `str` is a built-in type in python.

Comment: thank you for answer but I have to clarify more my question :
I'm trying to extract some information from web pages, so each time i found a kind of sentence but me i'm interesting in which is in bold. I give you the adress of the tree wab pages : 

- [link](http://www.nicolas.com/page.php/fr/18_409_9829_tourprignacgrandereserve.htm)

- [link](http://www.nicolas.com/page.php/fr/18_409_8236_relaisdedurfortvivens.htm)

- [link] (http://www.nicolas.com/page.php/fr/18_409_9068_leshautsdesmith.htm)

Comment: @xeroxSO Oh, but that changes everything... You might try this one, which looks for the specific title you're looking for: `res = re.search(r'<div class="pro_blk_trans_titre">.*?\s([^,]+),[^,]+</div>', myPage).group(1)`.